# AWS SQS triggered lambda suddenly stalling and not deleting messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda python function function that is connected to an SQS queue trigger with batch size 1. The SQS messages contain a file location on S3, along with a few metadata values.

When a message becomes available, the function reads some metadata from the file on S3 referenced in the message, creates a YAML file with more metadata which is then dumped to S3 and references the metadata file in an RDS database.

After I submit a load of messages to the queue (~1.7k) , all seems to go well initially, with the number of messages available dropping and the lambda executions ramping up.

But after some time, the execution time increases significantly to the point where the functions time out (time out is set at 90 secs). I don't see any errors in the logs, and the executions are still successfully (if they don't time out).

All of this can be seen in the monitoring:

[image]

Here in the lambda monitoring, you can see the sudden increase in duration, coinciding with a drop in concurrent executions and sudden appearance of errors (at worst there are two errors, 60 %s success rate). The gap you see is me disabling and enabling the trigger hoping for a change.

Here's the SQS monitoring for the same period:

[image]

You can see the number of messages visible leveling out at 192, and the number of messages received at 5. More puzzling for me, even though there are successful executions, the number of messages deleted drops to 0.

I really can't figure out why this issue is appearing now, I've been using this configuration w/o issues and changes.

Can it be that the SQS trigger configuration blocks the queue when there's a timeout reading from S3? Any clues?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The RDS cluster metrics:

[image]

Comment: Could be your RDS not keeping up with increasing number of connections or writes. Have you checked RDS metrics?

Comment: @Marcin I've checked it. We use a serverless cluster, which sits at capacity 2 and doesn't even scale to its maximum of 4. The max connections are 60, which does not seem too much IMO? I'll add the monitoring to the Q.

Comment: What is the visibility timeout for the queue? You need to figure out what causes the timeouts, maybe the objects are too large to retrieve within time / or your lambda runs out of memory during loading and is stuck at garbage collection, you temporarily perform too many S3 / KMS requests and get a SlowDown response, or something else in your lambda is being throttled.

Comment: @luk2302 the vis timeout is default 1 Minute. The objects in the S3 bucket are all roughly the same, so I can't really imagine why suddenly the execution time increases so much. Memory is also not the issue, using around 1/3 of the available mem. The bucket isn't encrypted, so KMS should not be a worry either.

Comment: You can try elimination method to troubleshoot. If possible, comment out code related to RDS, and check if this changes the behavior. If there is no much change, comment out maybe some S3 object processing part, and so on.

Comment: 1 minute of visibility timeout is certainly not a good idea if the lambda has a timeout of >1 minute. The queue should have a visibility timeout of (5 or 6) times the lambda timeout. Currently the lambda gets a message, maybe takes > 1 minute and then tries to delete the message but according to SQS the lambda no longer "owns" the message and cannot delete it.

Comment: And I agree with Marcin, comment stuff out, add logging statements in all sorts of places - you *need* to figure out what causes the timeout. We cannot really help any more than that because we have no idea what the lambda actually does.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for this, that could explain why the messages are not deleted even when the execution is successful potentially leading to the disruption.

Comment: Can you spot executions that take longer than 60 seconds? You can easily find those out using Cloudwatch log insights queries or maybe they are even displayed at the bottom of the lambda page.

Comment: @luk2302 yes, some take more than 60secs

Comment: @luk2302 I've increased the viz timeout to 6 mins, with lambda timeout to 2 mins. Still not sure why the execution time spikes, but the queue is moving again, with the lambda function chugging along in low concurrency until the queue is empty. So the blockage was caused by a too-low vis timeout on the SQS side? If so, kindly form it into an answer I can accept!

Comment: But that is only a partial answer, not the root cause. I would say the cause of events is the other way around: something caused the lambda to take a lot longer, some lambdas finished with > 1 minute, those that failed caused a spike in the metrics which causes the lambda service to reduce its polling, all that together caused the queue to not really move along anymore because no messages were deleted. The actual problem was and still is the misbehaving lambda itself.

Comment: @luk2302 Not to start a comment train here, but depending on the function, the issue can be indeed that SQS timeout and lambda timeout are misconfigured. In my case, it seems like an unexpected increase in execution time stalled the whole process.  After I've increased the limit, not only did the queue finish, the execution times normalized. I can see other users experiencing the same config issues, which is hard to fix if you are not aware of the connection - hence I believe an answer would be appropriate and helpful to others. But it's your decision

Comment: I can add that as an answer, yes. But note that the fact that the execution times now normalized further indicates that something like the RDS or S3 was slowing you down when the bulk of the messages were received. You should investigate that point further and / or add a concurrency limit on the queue. Having these kind of bulk messages cause troubles is common because even AWS takes time scaling up based on the requests and a basically instant peak does not give e.g. S3 enough time to scale.

Comment: By reducing the allowed concurrency you make the entire process take a bit longer but you can avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: @luk2302 point taken, I will investigate further. The peak concurrency of my lambda was at 70, which doesn't seem awfully much to me. But I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lambda successfully processes messages but the SQS queues does not delete any messages that most likely indicates a mismatch between the queue visibility timeout and the lambda timeout. You should make sure that the lambda service that picks up the message has enough time to finish the message and to tell SQS to delete the message. If the lambda takes 70 seconds but the queue only has a visibility timeout of 60s that means the `DeleteMessage` request by the lambda service will be silently rejected and the message will remain in the queue and will be re-processed again at a later time, potentially with the exact same outcome.

First note: If you have a concurrency limit set for the lambda the visibility timeout for the queue should not only be equal to the lambda timeout but to a multiple of the lambda timeout, 5 or 6 times the lambda timeout. The reason for that is that the lambda service may pick up the message, try to invoke a lambda, but the lambda throttles it, the lambda service then waits (lambda timeout) to retry the message. During all that the lambda services does not return the message to the queue, it keeps it in memory, does not extend the visibility timeout or anything like that. It retries a couple of (5 or 6 times) before the messages is actually discarded / returned to SQS. You should be able to try this out by creating a lambda with a timeout of e.g. 10 seconds, having it simply sleep / wait for 9 seconds, have a concurrency limit of 1 and then putting 1000 messages into the queue.

Second note: these kind of sudden bulk operations can cause all sorts of throttling issues that don't occur normally, either by other down-stream services of your own or even AWS' services. E.g. if your lambda performs an `assume-role` call or retrieves some config object from S3 having 500 requests the instant the messages are in the queue will often get you into trouble. The underlying database may become slow / unresponsive buffering all the incoming requests, etc.
An easy solution to that problem is to throttle the lambda by setting its concurrency limit. At that point make sure the queues has a proper visibility timeout as detailed in the previous section. And to make sure you are alerted of an actual increase in requests make sure that you watch `ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage` metric of the queue to be alerted if there is an increasing backlog.

Third note: if the lambda only misbehaves when a lot of requests are coming in one potential reason is a memory leak in the lambda. Since the execution contexts of a lambda are reused between different invocations the memory leak lives across different invocations as well. If there are few requests coming in you may always get a new execution context meaning the lambda starts with fresh memory each time, but if a lot of requests are coming in the execution contexts are certainly getting reused which might cause the leak to get so big the lambda basically freezes up due to garbage collection kicking in. Same goes for the `/tmp` directory in the lambda.